# How do I run the verilog code on a testbench?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, iverilog

I wrote the code for a ripple carry adder. Testbench is also available. How do I run this test bench on my Verilog code? I don't have a simulator. I am using the `iverilog` compiler.

**ripple_carry_adder.v**

```
module half_adder(a,b,sum,carry);
   input a,b;
   output sum,carry;
   assign sum=a^b;
   assign carry=a&b;
endmodule


module full_adder(a,b,cin,sum,cout);
   input a,b,cin;
   output sum,cout;
   wire   t1,t2;
   half_adder h(a,b,t1,t2);
   assign cout=t1&cin;
   assign sum=t1^cin;
   assign cout=t2|cout;
endmodule // full_adder

module ripple_carry_adder(input1,input2,answer);
   input [31:0] input1,input2;
   output [31:0] answer;
   wire [31:0]   carry;
   full_adder f(input1[0],input2[0],1'b0,answer[0],carry[0]);
   genvar            i;
   generate
      for(i=1;i<=31;i=i+1)
        begin : my_mabel
           full_adder f(input1[i],input2[i],carry[i-1],answer[i],carry[i]);
        end
   endgenerate
endmodule
```

**testbench**

```
module test;

reg [31:0] input1,input2, expected;
wire [31:0] actual;
integer seed;

ripple_carry_adder dut(input1,input2,actual);

initial begin
    seed = 0;
    repeat(10) begin
        input1 = $random(seed);
        input2 = $random(seed);
        expected = input1 + input2;
        #1;
        if(actual!=expected) $display("ERROR: %0d+%0d was %0d expected %0d",
            input1,input2,actual, expected);
        #9;
    end
end

endmodule
```

Comment: Here is your code on [EDA Playground](http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/81) The result pane also shows the command it ran: `iverilog -Wall design testbench && unbuffer vvp a.out`

Comment: @VictorLyuboslavsky http://www.edaplayground.com/s/45/84  the output is not displayed properly.

Comment: here your code modified with a working `$monitor`: http://www.edaplayground.com/s/4/85. There does seem to be a behavior difference between Icarus and other simulators. That should be a different question.

Comment: @VictorLyuboslavsky Why is the output of actual variable X? Additionally, even the expected value has wrong output in several cases.

Comment: Please create a new StackOverflow question for this new topic regarding the functional behavior of your code/testbench.

Answer (score 8):

Use:

```
$ iverilog -o ripple ripple_carry_adder.v ripple_carry_adder_tb.v
$ vvp ripple
```

to compile and run your code in terminal. You might add a `$monitor` to your testbench to be able to print some more results than just errors.

There is also a companion program called `GTKWave` that allows you to plot waveforms.

Comment: Nope. Ummm...monitor prints the value if even one of the elements in the sensitivity list changes its value, how can I avoid this and print the value after input1 and input2 have been assigned the values and actual and expected have been calculated?